# How to execute test cases in parallel using xdist plugin?

Tags: python, pytest, xdist

I have a pytest test suite with three parameterized test cases. I want to execute the three test cases in parallel. The sample test suite looks as follows.

```
### test_suite.py ###

def test_case1(param1, param2):
...
def test_case2(param1, param2):
...
def test_case3(param1, param2):
...
```

I want to create a python sub-process for each of these test cases and execute them in parallel.

I tried `py.test -d --tx 3*popen//python=python2.7 -s tests/test_suite.py`

However the test cases are not running in parallel. Am I missing something?

Refer documentation ([link](https://pytest.org/latest/xdist.html#running-tests-in-a-python-subprocess)):

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just call `py.test -n 3` ?